# How is the curvature of a vibrating string defined in classical mechanics?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, string

I think maybe under Fourier analysis the curvature of the string is not definable. Does a sine wave have a curvature?

Comment: *Does a sine wave have a curvature?* [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to understand the question. Also because two comments by Ghoster already implicitly answered the same. However, the **curvature** is, by definition, the inverse of the **curvature radius**. The latter is
$$R := \left|\frac{(1+y’^2)^{3/2}}{y’’}\right|$$
for a curve $y=y(x)$. So, evidently a sine has curvature…

The geometric meaning of the curvature radius at a point $p$ on the curve is the following one. It is the radius of the circle tangent at the curve in $p$ and such that it shares with the curve also the second derivative at $p$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition curvature is differential angular displacement vs differential arc length.

$\kappa = \frac{d \theta}{ds}$

$\tan \theta = y'\implies \sec ^2\theta (d\theta /dx) = y''\implies \frac{d \theta}{dx}=\frac{y''}{1+y'^2}$

$ds =\sqrt{1+y'^2} dx$

So $\kappa = \frac{d\theta}{ds}=\frac{d\theta /dx}{ds/dx}=\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}$

So if $y= \sin x, y'=\cos x, y''=-\sin x\implies \kappa = \frac{-\sin x}{(1+\cos ^2 x)^{3/2}}$